# how do I invoke a passed Method? This is delegation, right?

Tags: java, reflection, delegates

Ok, I *know* this is been asked and answered hundreds of times, and I know I'm probably going to get the "go search for the answer" response, but I'm going to try asking anyway.  Very simply, I want to pass a method and use it to do the writing of a string.  For example:

```
void writeStuff(Method method) {
    method.invoke("the string to write");
}
```

This way, I could hand it the method that would be receiving the string, such as System.out.print, or LOGGER.info.  Heck, why not *any* method that accepts a String as an

Answer (score 1):

For a non-static method you need its object, otherwise this owner can be null.
And then there are the exceptions to handle.

```
void writeStuff(Object owner, Method method) {
    method.invoke(owner, "the string to write");
}
```

Therefore till a next version of java, one uses an interface (with one method) and passes instances of these:

```
interface Printable { void print(String s); }

void writeStuff(Printable p) {
    p.print("...");
});

writeStuff(new Printable() {
    @Override public void print(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
});
```

---

For a static method, a function, one indeed needs no `this` (owner).
In a top ultimate language like Algol68 (1968 but still active!) one could do:

REAL y = IF c THEN sin ELSE cos FI (x);

were sin and cos are names for code values having type PROC(REAL)REAL.

Java make a sad distinction between field and method: you can have a field `int x` and method `void x(boolean)` with the same name, overloaded methods `boolean x()`. For something like function objects one never could use `System.out.println`.

Comment: I know, I'm struggling against the language rather than just accepting it.  But I feel like, if I'm passing a reference, shouldn't that be sufficient?  Am I not saying, "Here's an instance object, and, specifically, a method I want you to use."?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the documentation for invoke?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])

Comment: yep.  Even read the most [recent version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object[]%29)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the object on which the method should be called, too.

Indeed, you can read this from popular sources:

[Javadoc API 1.7 for invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

and

[Sun/Oracle tutorial on invoking methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

--tb